# Ruby on Rails : How to find a matching value in JSON arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

```
irb(main):001:0> d = OurDomains.find(3)
=> #<OurDomains:0x000000056ea410 @id="2", @internal_domains=["1.com", "2.com", "3.com"], @external_domains=["2.com"]>
```

Using the above response as an example, could someone give me a guide on how to compare values in the internal_domains and external_domains array please? Specially, I am interested in displaying all the values in internal_domains that corresponds to a value in external_domains in my view.html.erb; that is "2.com" in this case

Comment: You want `d.internal_domains & d.external_domains` ? [Intersection](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@internal_domains & @external_domains
```

Comment: @user2782109 is my comment visible to you ?

Comment: What do you mean truncate the result?